# Run GUI programs in Docker in Ubuntu

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, docker

I used to run programs with commands like this:

```
docker run -ti \
  --name wireshark \
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
-v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority \
--privileged \
  -d ubuntu:17.10 /bin/bash
```

then I could run wireshark using my Ubuntu's system's display.
Like this page's example: [Running GUI App with docker](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/)

Now it is not working. When I run wireshark I get this error:

```
root@5ad127a8333a:/# wireshark 
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to solve this with

`xhost +`

but it would then be wise to do

`xhost -`

after you no longer use this container.

In fact the more restrictive

`xhost +local:docker`

is enough

Comment: Nice. Do you know why the way I did before does not work anymore?

Comment: I forgot to mention param (-v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority ) the way I did before

Comment: im facing the same problem could you please write again the full cmd or instructions

Comment: You should open a new thread and put all commands and messages