# How to restart the ROS docker container with GUI enabled

Tags: docker, user-interface, ros

- How to **restart** the ROS docker container **with** GUI enabled?  (Points to note: restart & with GUI!)

Following from questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099483/run-gui-programs-in-docker-in-ubuntu) and [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/326807/docker-gazeb-cannot-connect-to-x-server/) and the docker tutorial for ROS [here](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI) I managed to stumble on to how one can "run" a docker container with GUI enabled.

It goes something like this:

```
$ xhost +local:docker
$ docker run -it --env="DISPLAY" --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority" ros
```

Afterwards, I can run inside the container in a terminal the following commands:

```
# roscore
```

And then in a separate terminal:

```
$ docker exec -it priceless_engelbart bash
# apt-get update
# apt-get install ros-melodic-rqt-gui
# rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui
```

And a window appears, which shows that the GUI is working from inside the container.

[image]

**Question:** The problem is, I don't want to create a new container every time, which is what the `docker run` command does. I have done work in the first container. Why would I want to completely ignore that and spin up a new container and start from scratch?

To remedy the situation, I looked into [docker start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/), [docker restart](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/restart/), [docker attach](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) and  [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), to see if there was anyway to pass those extra parameters that I pass to `docker run`, like `--env` and `--volume` to help make the GUI work inside the container here.

Unfortunately, those commands do NOT allow passing any such parameters.

I have not been able to find a solution till now for the situation.

Comment: Docker start simply restarts the container using same settings as were passed using the Docker run.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the 9 min since I posted this question, I tested that scenario. But what about the container where I did not 'run' the container with the gui specific parameters?

Comment: You have to recreate the container. Use `docker-compose` instead. If any settings are changed it will recreate container for you, no need for low level `docker run` command.

Comment: @emix, ok. I try out docker-compose. Thank you for the hint. `:)`

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26833005/2955790) explains the solution to my problem and also the fundamental misunderstanding of mine regarding containers. I should not be storing data in the container that I depend on.